# Getters Setters with user input

Tags: java, getter

Is using getters and setters with userinput a good practice? I looked for some example but was not able to find any. While the code below works but is this a good practice?  I noticed If I use the code below I am not able to use constructor.   Thank You for your explanation.

```
public class Tests{

    private String name;
    private int id;

    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setName(){
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        name= userinput.next();     
    }

    public String getName(){

        return name;
    }

    public void displayInfo(){
        setName();
        System.out.println("You entered " + this.getName());
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Tests test = new Tests();
        test.displayInfo();

    }

}
```

Comment: do you want the program to stop while it waits for user input on the command line when your setter is called?

Comment: Not able to use the constructor? What do you mean?

Comment: No that is not good practice, a set method should have a parameter with the new value to set for the field. In general your data (id, name) should be in one class and gathering of the data should be handled by another class.

Comment: If I use constructor then, Tests test = new Tests(name, id); I have to type a name/id. However I want the user to be able to supply that name and ID.

Comment: @SheikhRahman see my comment above for that issue

Comment: Thank You all for the explanation,this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your one is not good practice. You can follow this one. Take input in main function and then set input value to name using

```
public void setName( String name){
      this.name =name;
}
```

Or you can use another method like `takeInput(){}` and call it from main method and then set in setter method. Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Tests tests= new Tests();
   String inputString =tests.takeInput();
   tests.setName(inputString);
   tests.displayInfo();
}
```

And takeInput() will like this

```
public String takeInput(){
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String str =userinput.next();
    return str;
}
```

`displayInfo()` simply display data

And you are already using a constructor when creating Test class object. This is called default constructor. You can also define parameterized constructor like

```
Tests(String name){
      this.name = name;
}
```

But in this case you don't need to declare parameterized constructor.

And for more better design you can create another class like Info.java where you can define class members like name and its getter and setter and can use Tests class only for main method.

Comment: This will not compile, you're mixing static and non-static methods in an incorrect way and keywords are missing. Please clean up you code (and also add some indentation) so this answer reaches an acceptable level.

Comment: Here I explained scenerio. Not giving exact code. This question for analysis not for code running. Thats why i think its not concern

Comment: This answer might be helpful or a guidance for other beginners since it is marked as accepted so making it as correct as possible is important in my opinion to avoid unnecessary confusion. Besides, don’t you put some pride in your effort and want it to be as good as possible?

Comment: Sure i will update. I gave this answer from mobile. When i will get access of laptop i will update. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 6):

I would say this is terrible practice. It violates the "bean" contract, and it doesn't follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (it mutates and prompts for a value). This,

```
public void setName(){
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    name= userinput.next();     
}
```

Should just be

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;     
}
```

And then (don't make `Scanner` a field for no reason) something like

```
public void displayInfo() {
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    setName(userinput.nextLine()); 
    System.out.println("You entered " + this.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change the setName() method with 1 parameter. It will be cleanand will help to be away from many bugs. And you have to do some changes to getName() method. And remove the scanner in the class decleration.

```
        //setName
        public void setName(String n) {
            this.name = n;
        }

        //getName
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        //main method.
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setName(s.next());
            test.displayInfo();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setName(String name){ this.name=name; }

and in the main when you call:

test.setName(userinput.nextLine());
```